# How can I create this type of layout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How can I create this layout in Android? I need a layout with autocomplete edit text and dynamic text.

Comment: There are few libraries available on github  
[https://github.com/hootsuite/nachos](https://github.com/hootsuite/nachos)
[https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput](https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput)
[https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)
[https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips](https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips)
 You can choose one of them which best suits as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you have to add custom textview and auto complete edit text on any layout at run time(dynamic time).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chips with LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) for explanation of `Chips`

I think you need this:

Filter Chip
Use filter chips containing tags or descriptive words to filter a collection.

This style usually contains an optional chip icon, an optional close icon, and is always checkable.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
```

and Handling Clicks by using this:

```
Chip chip = (Chip) findViewById(R.id.chip);

chip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Handle the click.
    }
});
```